# is it possible to target a player as if they were a Planeswalker?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I ask this question so that I can clarify an old description. Players, from before there was castable Planeswalkers, have been described as Planeswalkers themselves and I understand that after each battle at a card shop the player gets that description again due to the Planeswalker point system. But my question lies between the past and the post battle are players classified as Planeswalkers when it comes to card effects?

Comment: Related: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/21086/can-older-cards-that-refer-to-a-player-opponent-ever-be-used-on-planeswalkers?rq=1

Comment: Also: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/35245/is-player-interchangeable-with-planeswalker?rq=1

Comment: And... https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/15161/can-guttersnipe-hit-planeswalkers?rq=1. Though I don't think any of these are actual duplicates of your question.

Comment: The planeswalker vs. Player question seems to pop up fairly frequently, it would be nice to have a definitive "what are the differences between a Player and a Planeswalker" question to link to. This question might be suitable for it?

Answer (score 9):

No, you cannot target a player as if they were a planeswalker, and you cannot target a planeswalker as though it was a player. Saying that players are "planeswalkers" is simply part of the flavor of the game.

That being said, there are a couple of ways in which the rules treat planeswalkers as similar to players. While declaring attacks, you may declare that a creature is attacking a planeswalker instead of a player. That creature can be blocked by creatures the planeswalker's controller controls, and it deals combat damage to the planeswalker instead of the player. This is specified in [rule 508.1b](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Declare_attackers_step):

> If the defending player controls any planeswalkers, or the game allows the active player to attack multiple other players, the active player announces which player or planeswalker each of the chosen creatures is attacking.

In addition, many effects that deal damage to a player also deal damage to planeswalkers, and the common "any target" wording refers to creatures, players, and planeswalkers. Just about every effect that dealt damage to players printed before the Dominaria set was released in 2018 received errata to also damage planeswalkers. This is because the rules before Dominaria allowed players to choose to redirect noncombat damage from opponents to that player's planeswalkers, and the update preserved that functionality after that rule was removed.

Answer (score 3):

No.

A player is not a planeswalker, and a planeswalker is not a player. They are 2 completely separate things.

There are a couple ways in which you can go after a planeswalker with methods previously reserved for going after players:

> 306.6. Planeswalkers can be attacked. (See rule 508, “Declare Attackers Step.”)
>
> 306.7. If noncombat damage would be dealt to a player by a source controlled by an opponent, that opponent may have that source deal that damage to a planeswalker the first player controls instead. This is a redirection effect (see rule 614.9) and is subject to the normal rules for ordering replacement effects (see rule 616). The opponent chooses whether to redirect the damage as the redirection effect is applied.

However, there is no way to target a player using a card that targets planewalkers.